# Making a series of photos fade in and out sequentially on a web page using Slick

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slick.js

I would like a series of three images to automatically fade in and out over and over looping on the web page without any user input. Upon suggestion in the comments, I have decided to use the Slick library and have generated the following code:

```
$('.fade').slick({
    accessibility: false,
    arrows: false,
    draggable: false,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 3000,
    fade: true,
    speed: 1000,
    swipe: false,
    touchMove: false,
});
```

It works great for one cycle, and then it completely breaks with images flickering and turning black. Does anyone know how to remedy this?

Comment: Look at autoplay function of [slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)

Comment: Try to use http://bxslider.com/

Comment: @El.oz bxslider is becoming more fruitful than Slick, but I can't change the width of the slider!! It insists on fixing my pictures to a specific width. How do I change this?

Comment: @Confiqure sorry i  didn't use slick before, try to inspect the div which has the problem and give it the width in css with !important...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use code from this Fiddle to accomplish my goals.  All I had to do was slightly rework some of the methods, but this is perfectly what I needed.

http://jsfiddle.net/pdb4kb1a/2/

The JavaScript boils down to:

```
var imgArray = [
    'http://placehold.it/300x200',
    'http://placehold.it/200x100',
    'http://placehold.it/400x300'],
    curIndex = 0;
    imgDuration = 3000;
function slideShow() {
    document.getElementById('slider').className += "fadeOut";
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById('slider').src = imgArray[curIndex];
        document.getElementById('slider').className = "";
    },1000);
    curIndex++;
    if (curIndex == imgArray.length) { curIndex = 0; }
    setTimeout(slideShow, imgDuration);
}
slideShow();
```